# Shell scripting help text file into array

Tags: bash, shell-script, array, read

```
#!/bin/bash
function guest {
i=0
while IFS = $'\n' read -r name; do
GUESTS[i]="${name}"
((i++))
done<filename.txt
}
function print{
i=0
while ((${GUESTS[@]} > $i)) do
echo "${GUESTS[i++]}\n" 
done
}
```

In the code that I've provided above, I'm trying to two have two functions, the first function is to take any text file with a list of random peoples names (ex. Bob\n, Jennifer\n, Caleb\n, etc) and convert it into an array of GUESTS. The code MUST BE in the ARRAY OF GUESTS. Then on the 2nd function is should print out the array of GUESTS with each name having its own line.

Comment: What results do you get when you run your script?  Do you have a question regarding your results?

Comment: (1) Please indent code properly when posting to [SE]. (2) Your question doesn’t contain a question! While it’s obvious that you want help getting your script to work, you are still expected to phrase your question in the form of a question. (3) If you want help getting your script to work, you really should tell us what it’s doing now. What can you conclude from the behavior you are seeing? What research have you done to try to debug/diagnose this? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: So, it isn't running. When i try to run my code ./MyProject -list
It's blank, it doesn't print out the array GUESTS like I have to.

Comment: I keep getting this error 
line 75: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
 line 75: `      while ((${GUESTS[@]} > $i)) do'

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the bash built-in `mapfile`:

```
$ cat /tmp/file.txt 
Bob
Jennifer
Caleb
$ mapfile -t guests < /tmp/file.txt
$ printf '%s\n' "${guests[@]}"
Bob
Jennifer
Caleb
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first function, Bash has made it easy for you. Here's all you need to do:

```
readarray GUESTS < filename.txt
```

For the second one, It should look something like this:

```
print () {
   for index in ${!GUESTS[@]}; do
   echo ${GUESTS[$index]}
   done
}
```